# How do I merge in Git?

Tags: git

I have cloned a remote repository and modified a few of the files locally. I want to update my local working copy with any new changes done at the remote repository. As this is "read-only" (no updates wanted) my goal is to merge any changes from the remote to my local changes.

I thought the proper command for doing this was just "merge". However after issuing that in bash I get the following response:

> $ git merge
>   error: merge is not possible because you have unmerged files.
>   hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm '
>   hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
>   fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.

Could someone please help me out of this Git mess? All I want to do is update my local files with the remote changes and if possibly merge any files that's been updated both locally and remotely.

What does "merge is not possible because you have unmerged files." means?

Comment: Start with `git status`, and then read *any Git tutorial*. Start with [the official one](http://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial). `git merge` is not how you pull changes from the remote repository. Instead of trying commands at random, learn to use the tool.

Comment: Well as you could read in my post before you changed it I already have done that. Read tutorials. The link you give is more or less just a list of commands with some explanation. I don't think it's very kind done of you first removing my text about not understanding the git messages and lack of useful git help and then refer to just another incomprehensive documentation. Why do you think i posted my question in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Use `git status` and see the files that you have changed and commit/discard/stash
(`git reset --hard`)
 them before merging

Comment: I get the message "discard is not a git command"